# Python Pandas read_csv() taking in information related to my laptop unnecessarily

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am working with some labels for some audio data. When I read in the csv I change the names of the columns. For some reason though it is as if there are two dataframes being read in, one with the information that I care about from the csv, and another that contains my username and type of laptop I am using as well as the current time on my computer.

Code:

```
# initializing the output dataframe that will contain all of the labels and the relevant metadata
# across each audio clip in a dataset. Should be in the format to work with it in the Python package
manual_df = pd.DataFrame()
# the ground truth labels lack column names, so I am filling them in closer to the end product
column_names = ["OFFSET","MANUAL ID"]
for clip_annotations in os.listdir(label_path):
    # isolating the name of the clip from the csv file
    # will be used to extract the metadata from the equivelant wav file
    x = clip_annotations.split('.')
    clip_name = x[0]
    # taking in the labels for the audio clip
    clip_df = pd.read_csv(label_path+clip_annotations,names=column_names)
    print(clip_df)
    # removing the annotations that occur over the same interval in the clip
    # first step in converting multi-class classifier into binary classifier.
    clip_df = clip_df.drop_duplicates(subset = ["OFFSET"])
    # second step to converting multi-class classifier to binary classifier
    # Isn't all that necessary since we don't use the MANUAL ID Column that much yet
    clip_df["MANUAL ID"] = "bird"
    # splitting the time into OFFSET and DURATION
    new = clip_df["OFFSET"].str.split("-", n = 1, expand = True)
    clip_df["OFFSET"] = new[0]
    clip_df["DURATION"] = 5
    #print(clip_df)
    # converting hours minutes seconds format into seconds
    new = clip_df["OFFSET"].str.split(":", n = 2, expand = True)
    #print(new)
    #new = new.rename(columns={"Hours","Minutes","Seconds"})
    #seconds_offset = new[0]*3600 + new[1]*60 + new[2]
    #print(seconds_offset)
new
```

```
output: 
                                         OFFSET  \
NaN jacob jacob-Aspire-E5-575  26.03.2021 13:49   

                                                               MANUAL ID  
NaN jacob jacob-Aspire-E5-575  file:///home/jacob/.config/libreoffice/4;  
                OFFSET MANUAL ID
0    00:00:00-00:00:05   cintin1
1    00:00:05-00:00:10   cintin1
2    00:00:05-00:00:10   citwoo1
3    00:00:10-00:00:15   butwoo1
4    00:00:10-00:00:15   cintin1
..                 ...       ...
319  00:09:50-00:09:55    meapar
320  00:09:50-00:09:55   strwoo2
321  00:09:55-00:10:00   butwoo1
322  00:09:55-00:10:00   hauthr1
323  00:09:55-00:10:00    meapar

[324 rows x 2 columns]
```

My goal is to make it so that I am no longer picking up the unnecessary information related to my laptop

Answer (score 0):

I went back through and printed the clip_annotations and it turns out that the files I am interested in are having some duplicated "lock" files that look something like this: .~lock.PER49_20190131.csv#
not sure why that was occurring, but for my situation here, this script doesn't need to be general, so I am just coding around it with this conditional at the beginning of the loop:

```
if clip_annotations.startswith(".~lock."):
        continue
```